# How can I manipulate discord objects?

Tags: object, python-3.6, discord

```
import discord
import discord.ext
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio

bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='v.')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(bot.user.name)


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def role(ctx):
    user_role=ctx.message.author.roles
    print(user_role)


bot.run('bot token')
```

I want to get the role names of the user that used the command be able to remove the command from the user, but I'm getting this response

```
[<discord.role.Role object at 0x067A83B0>, <discord.role.Role object at 0x067A8530>, <discord.role.Role object at 0x067A84B0>, <discord.role.Role object at 0x067A8630>]
```

How can I manipulate discord objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all the attributes of a `discord.Role` object [here](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role). So you could do

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def role(ctx):
    user_role=ctx.message.author.roles
    for r in user_role:
        print(r.name)
```

Comment: I get the names in a drop-down order `Member` `Pink` `@Everyone` how can I make a variable represent only a single one of them?

Comment: `user_role` is a list... If you wanted the first one, you'd do `user_role[0].name`... Second one, you'd do `user_role[1].name` and so on